# backgroundworker not firing RunWorkerCompleted event

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

i have a web application with a search form. The form is being used to search through my own database, but also at other databases through their API service. To provide a fast response, i have decided to split the work in main thread and the backgroundworker service.

Here is my method which runs the search task.

```
// search through other API
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.RunWorkerAsync(form);

// search in my api
...

// wait for API results
while (worker.IsBusy) {
    for (sbyte i = 0; i < sbyte.MaxValue; i++) ;
}
// handle data and show to user
```

And the methods are

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    Forms f = e.Argument as Forms;
    if (f != null) {
        List<ApiResponse> result = GetDataFromOtherApi(f);
        e.Result = result;
    }
    else e.Result = null;
}
```

The `GetDataFromOtherApi()` method works fine in the single thread test. It also works when running the backgroundworker thread. I have set a breakpoint at the end and `e.Result` has values which i was looking for.

```
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    List<ApiResponse> reply = e.Result as List<ApiResponse>;

    if (reply == null) ar = null;
    else if (reply.Any()) ar = reply;
    else ar = null;
}
```

the `ar` is a variable that the main thread can access to after the while loop has done with running. But, when placing a breakpoint at the start, it never stops there, the loop itself is continuous to the infinity ... It means that the event is never being fired.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: never wait using a loop (In a high level programming language literally never!). That takes a hell lot of processor time for nothing. You have lots of different synchronization methods that provides better perfomance.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` doesn't have a `Join()` method from Threading. (sadly). There is a workaround of it true, but it all ends on "waiting" for it.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is designed and intended for cooperation with a Windows UI Message pump. There is no Message loop in Web apps so don't use a Bgw here. There are documented patterns for async handling of webrequests.

Comment: If you just wanted to let something run in the background and then display "something" when it finishes then remove that infinite loop and put the call to "handle data and show to user" inside the RunWorkerCompleted handler (be careful when accessing UI elements). Not locking up threads will allow more processor more time slice to the threads doing real work. Also, although it doesn't sound like the problem, if there was an error in the worker then accessing "e.Result" in the completion handler may throw an exception which you aren't catching. Try testing e.Error first.

Answer (score 4):

The `BackgroundWorker` progress & completed events are synchronised to run on the UI thread.  I'd guess as you're blocking that thread, they'll never get fired.